# Express Multer req.files is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Whenever I upload an image, req.files returns undefined.
This is my code:

```
 var upload123 = multer({
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp'),
  });

  app.post(upload123);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<form action="/images" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="file" class="col-md-2 control-label">Browse:</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the controller I am trying to access req.files in:

```
create(req, res) {
const saveImage = function() {
  const possible = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  let imgUrl = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    imgUrl += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }

  Models.Image.find({ filename: imgUrl }, (err, images) => {
    if (images.length > 0) saveImage();
    else {
      var tempPath = req.files.file.path,
      ext = path.extname(req.files.file.name).toLowerCase(),
      targetPath = path.resolve(`./public/upload/${ imgUrl }${ ext }`);

      if (ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg' || ext === '.gif') {
        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          var newImg = new Models.Image({
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description,
            filename: imgUrl + ext
          });

          newImg.save((err, image) => {
            res.redirect(`/images/${image.uniqueId}`);
          });
        });
  } else {
    fs.unlink(tempPath, () => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(500, {error: 'Only image files are allowed'});
    })
  }
    }
  });

}

saveImage();
```

}

I am using Express version 4.16.3 and Multer 1.3.0.
I check the docs but couldn't figure out how to simply provide a `dest` option in Multer. Please help, am new to Nodejs

Comment: How your route looks?

Answer (score 0):

This is example from code that is working properly:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const fileUpload = multer({storage});

app.use('/*', fileUpload.single('file'));
```

If you have this in beginning of your application and you put controllers after this middleware, then in `req.file` you will have file

The best thing is that it is stored directly in memory, not in some file, so you dont have to load it from filesystem. (which is also safer, especially when you deploy your app to some cloud services and containers, which makes it less visible)

---

If you insist on your "file-on-disk" solution, based on official docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer you should use it as this:

```
  var upload123 = multer({
    dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp'),
  });

  app.post('/endpoint/to/upload/photos', upload123.single('file'), controller.handleImage);
```

Comment: But how do I provide a `dest` to store the data? I think in the previous version we had an object param for setting destination.
How to achieve the same in this version cuz I wasn't able to find info about the same in the documentation.

Comment: @AdityaRaj - its 2018, you dont want to handle it directly in your filesystem. You can use i.e. https://cloudinary.com/ if you want to later to change the picture before sending (i.e. resizing it to the smaller size). Or just send it to S3 storage.

Comment: but is there any way to include the dest...i am completely new to nodejs and need to follow along with the book.

Comment: Also, there is another error, it says multer.single('file') is not a function.